# In python 3.2, how to compare a symbols e.g. >

Tags: python

Im writing a function which will guess what number I'm thinking of, but how do I compare a symbol like a > or less than symbol?

```
def NumberGuess (low,high):
    guess = ((low+high//2)

    if str(input(guess,"?")) == (">") :
         NumberGuess (guess,high)
    elif str(input(guess,"?")) == "<":
         NumberGuess (low,guess)
    else:
         str(input(guess,"?")) == "="
```

This is what I have so far, I could do it another way but this is bugging me now and I wanna figure it out
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
def NumberGuess (lo,hi):
    guess = (lo+hi)//2
    user_guess = input("Please, input '>' or '<' as a guess: ")
    if user_guess == ">" :
        ReverseNumberGuess (guess,hi)
    elif user_guess == "<":
        ReverseNumberGuess (lo,guess)
```

Comment: Thats returning error messages for me, it highlights user_guess as the source of the error???

Comment: There was an error in the `guess =` line; I've corrected it. Try that.

Comment: I noticed it after an intense staring contest with my laptop.. thanks!